# What order to read Kage Baker's "The Company" books, novellas and short stories

Tags: time-travel, suggested-order

There are 9 books, 4 novellas, and short stories written by Kage Baker in her *The Company* universe.  I'm wondering what order to read them in.  It is especially confusing because they are about time travel, so reading the blubs is not-so-helpful.

I read *In the Garden of Iden* and *Sky Coyote* back in the 90s and there was a hint the series was building to a big secret.  I'd rather not read one that gives it away before its time and ruin the earlier ones.

Can someone who has read them all please tell me the best order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](http://www.librarything.com/series/The+Company) has a pretty complete reckoning. The main novel sequence goes:

1. In the Garden of Iden
2. Sky Coyote
3. Mendoza in Hollywood
4. The Graveyard Game
5. The Life of the World to Come
6. The Children of the Company
7. The Machine's Child
8. The Sons of Heaven

There's a bunch of short stories, but as I recall you don't need them for continuity; if you want to read them, interspersing them among the main books where LibraryThing suggests works pretty well. Of the prequels, you can read The Empress of Mars whenever you feel like it; it's set in the same universe, but it's a totally independent story. I haven't read Not Less Than Gods yet, but the summaries I've seen of it online make it sound really spoilerish, so you should probably save it for last or near-last.

Answer (score 1):

Of the short-story collections, perhaps put *Black Projects, White Knights* between 4 & 5; and put *Gods and Pawns* between 7 & 8.

They are listed in that order in the front of my copy of *The Sons of Heaven*. And that follows the publication dates.